# Как удалить каскадно данные из таблицы

Tags: postgresql

Пытаюсь удалить данные из одной таблицы, она связана с другой.
String sql = "DELETE FROM transactions  WHERE id = ? ; DELETE FROM transactions_to_categories  WHERE transactions_id = ? "; Так не получается, а примера каскадного удаления не нашел.

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы работало каскадное удаление, используют модификацию таблицы

Например, для каскадного удаления записей в таблице `some_table`

```
ALTER TABLE some_table ADD FOREIGN KEY (some_fk)
REFERENCES another_table(some_id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Мы указываем ее связь с `another_table` и что удалять записи нужно каскадно `ON DELETE CASCADE`, кстати помимо этого вполне уместно использовать и ключ `ON UPDATE CASCADE` для каскадного обновления записей.

Далее, при удалении записей в `another_table` они так же удалятся из `some_table`

```
DELETE FROM another_table WHERE some_field='value';
```